# How to rename multiple netCDF files in a folder with dates inside these using python script?

Tags: python, datetime, netcdf, weatherdata

I have 28 files for example :-

File -> `day01.nc` inside file:-

```
| lat | lon | date      |
| --- | --- | --------  |
| 7   | 68  | 2021-02-01|
| 7   | 69  | 2021-02-01|
```

File -> `day02.nc` inside file:-

```
| lat | lon | date      |
| --- | --- | --------  |
| 7   | 68  | 2021-02-02|
| 7   | 69  | 2021-02-02|
```

File -> `day28.nc` inside file:-

```
| lat | lon | date      |
| --- | --- | --------  |
| 7   | 68  | 2021-02-28|
| 7   | 69  | 2021-02-28|
```

I want to convert their name according to date format like `temp_ind20210201.nc`, `temp_ind20210202.nc`,...,`temp_ind20210328.nc` using python script.

**Note :-** In `day01.nc` the date format inside that file is like `2021-02-01` and so on.
I was trying :-

```
DATA_DIR = 'data'
today = datetime.datetime.now()
offset_1day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
re_number = re.compile('day(\d{,2})\.nc')

for fname in glob.glob(DATA_DIR + "/*.nc"):
      number_string = re_number.search(fname)
if not number_string:
      continue
   number_of_days = int(number_string.group(1))
   str_timestamp = (today + (number_of_days - 1) * offset_1day).strftime("%Y%m%d")
   new_fname = f"{DATA_DIR}/temp_ind{_str_timestamp}.nc"
   print(f'{fname} -> {new_fname}')
   os.rename(fname, new_fname)
```

Comment: how are u deciding the `month`?

Comment: actually this is current month data starts from date 17-02-2021 to end with 18-03-2021.

Comment: you also could have edited your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66345679/10197418), it can be re-opened. Anyways, regarding your question as it is now, so you basically want to read the nc file, extract the first entry from "date", close the file and rename it according to what you have extracted?

Comment: yes that is what I want using python script. I am not able to get the date from inside the file and set it into the file name. Please help.

Comment: did you have a look at [netCDF4](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/)? there's also some questions related to reading nc files in Python here on SO. for your specific case, it is kind of difficult to give a good answer without an example .nc file (there could be groups, date could be in different formats etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question and comments beneath it, you want to be able to extract the first date in a NetCDF file and use that to generate a new file name for that file. The following should work, but might need tweaking, depending on how time is formatted:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset("infile.nc")
"temp_ind" + ds.time[0].values.astype("str")[0:10].replace("-","") + ".nc"
```

Comment: Sir, I want automated code by which I can rename multiple files at once.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you not know how to code? Simply asking people on SO to solve a problem for you is very much against the spirit of things.

Comment: actually I am not able to know that how to automate this thing. So I want help in this.

Comment: I suggest writing a for loop that will do files one at a time. Did you try that?

Comment: yes in that case it is giving me wrong dates. I want date that is written inside the .nc file as a file name.

Comment: Please revise your question to include your code and make an effort to make this reproducible. Why did your code fail?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this in a loop from the command line in bash. I pipe the output from CDO to awk, in case any file has more than one date, this will ensure that the file is renamed to the **first** date in the file

```
for file in day*.nc ; do 
   mv $file temp_ind`cdo -s showdate $file | awk '{print $1}'`.nc
done
```

note that CDO outputs a date with hyphens yyyy-mm-dd, so you get a filename with hyphens included - you can remove those with a second pipe to **sed** if you don't like that.